# An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager (with specified fields)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-applications

I know this question has been asked a ton of times, but I think the fact that I'm specifying modified fields is making it a little tougher for me to solve.  Here's my update method (in repository):

```
        public Folder UpdateFolder(Folder folder)
        {
            _db.Folders.Attach(folder); // error happens here
            var entry = _db.Entry(folder);
            entry.Property(e => e.Title).IsModified = true;
            SaveChanges();
            return entry.Entity;
        }
```

I get "An object with the same key already exists" when I try to Attach.  If I remove that line, I get "The entity of type "folder" does not exist in this context".

Here's where I'm calling it from (test method):

```
        homeFolder = _dtoServices.AddFolder(new FolderDto
            {
                Title = "Home Folder"
            });
        Assert.AreEqual(_dtoServices.GetHomeData().TotalFolders, 1);

        // Check Folder
        Assert.AreEqual(_dtoServices.GetFolder(homeFolder.FolderId).Details, "Home Folder");

        // Update Folder, Check Folder
        homeFolder.Title = "Updated";
        _dtoServices.UpdateFolder(homeFolder); // HERE
        Assert.AreEqual(_dtoServices.GetFolder(homeFolder.FolderId).Details, "Updated");
```

In my DtoServices:

```
        public FolderDto UpdateFolder(FolderDto folderDto)
        {     
            var test = _repository.UpdateFolder(folderDto.ToEntity());
            return null;
        }
```

In my FolderDto:

```
public class FolderDto
{
    public FolderDto()
    {
    }

    public FolderDto(Folder folder)
    {
        FolderId = folder.FolderId;
        Title = folder.Title;          
    }

    [Key]
    public int FolderId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Folder ToEntity()

     {
        var folder = new Folder
        {
            FolderId = FolderId,
            Title = Title,
        };
        return folder;
    }
 }
```

Any idea why this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely here: `folderDto.ToEntity()`. I guess in `_dtoServices.AddFolder` you have created a `Folder` entity and added it to the context, then called `SaveChanges`, then placed the generated `Id` in the returned `homeFolder` DTO. The entity `Folder` is still attached to the context and after `SaveChanges` in state `Unchanged`.

In `UpdateFolder` by calling `folderDto.ToEntity()` you create a new entity instance `var folder = new Folder...` with the same Id that you have returned from `AddFolder`. Then you attach this new instance to the same context where the old instance from `AddFolder` with the same key is still attached to ==> another "object with the same key" ==> exception.

Either detach the old entity before you attach the new one, or use `Find` to check if there isn't already an entity with the same key. If yes, update *this* entity and don't attach the other object.